# How do I CONCAT data from a dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have built the following function and now .append will be removed from pandas in a future version. So I am weeling to convert this code with concat.

```
def MyDF(self,DF1,DF2):
    OutputDf = pd.DataFrame([]).reset_index(drop=True)
    for i in range(0,len(DF2)):
        OutputDf = OutputDf.append(DF2.loc[[i]])
        OutputDf = OutputDf.append(DF1.loc[(DF1['TheName'] == DF2['TheName'][i]) & (DF1['WGT'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) > 0) ])
        OutputDf = OutputDf.reset_index(drop=True)
    return OutputDf
```

I don't know how to use `concat` in this case, so how would I avoid `.append` there ?

Not sure that would work :

```
OutputDf = pd.Concat(OutputDf,DF2.loc[[i]])
```

Comment: Please read these examples: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: The documentation says it all: [deprecated .append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)

Comment: @GedasMiksenas thank you for this documentation but I don't understand how to use it in my case. I try to concatenate row by row ...

Do I just need to do : `Frames = [DF2.loc[[i]],DF1.loc[(DF1['TheName'] == DF2['TheName'][i]) & (DF1['WGT'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) > 0) ]]` and then `Output = pd.concat(Output,Frames)` ?

Comment: @imburningbabe Would you mind give me an example ? Not sure to understand how this works

Comment: You can just replace  `df1 = df1.append(df2)` with `df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True`, whatever dataframes df1 and df2 are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and [`pandas.Series.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) are Deprecated since version 1.4.0. See [Deprecated DataFrame.append and Series.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)

The alternative is using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

In OP's case, `.append()` is being used in two cases:

1. `OutputDf = OutputDf.append(DF2.loc[[i]])`
2. `OutputDf = OutputDf.append(DF1.loc[(DF1['TheName'] == DF2['TheName'][i]) & (DF1['WGT'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) > 0) ])`

---

**Case 1**

One can change to the following

```
OutputDf = pd.concat([OutputDf, DF2.loc[[i]]], ignore_index=True)
```

---

**Case 2**

One can change to the following

```
OutputDf = pd.concat([OutputDf, DF1.loc[(DF1['TheName'] == DF2['TheName'][i]) & (DF1['WGT'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) > 0) ]], ignore_index=True)
```

---

**Notes:**

- As I do not have access to the dataframes and do not know the desired output, one might have to do some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

I think [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) is easy to understand, so that, you just tell good bye to append and keep up to pandas.

At the beginning, just attention to *objs, ignore_index* and *axis* arguments. If you want to add rows one under the other, just you can give this with **axis=0** argument. If you give axis=0, you can concat dataFrame objects vertically like `.append()`. If you give axis=1, this process will be done horizontally like the documentation says:

> **axis : {0/’index’, 1/’columns’}, default 0
>
> The axis to concatenate along.**

Also, you can use `ignore_index` rather than `reset_index`. To organize indexes, you can use `ignore_index=True` argument.

Summarily, if you have 2 dataframes to concat like your question, you can use something like this:

```
def MyDF(self,DF1,DF2):
    OutputDf = pd.DataFrame([]).reset_index(drop=True)
    for i in range(0,len(DF2)):
        process1 = DF2.loc[[i]]
        process2 = DF1.loc[(DF1['TheName'] == DF2['TheName'][i]) & (DF1['WGT'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) > 0) ]
        OutputDf = pd.concat([process1, process2], ignore_index=True)
    return OutputDf
```

You can make this code much shorter but it will decrease to readability, obviously. You may want to use:

```
def MyDF(self,DF1,DF2):
    OutputDf = pd.DataFrame([]).reset_index(drop=True)
    for i in range(0,len(DF2)):
        OutputDf = pd.concat([DF2.loc[[i]], DF1.loc[(DF1['TheName'] == DF2['TheName'][i]) & (DF1['WGT'].apply(lambda x: float(x)) > 0) ]], ignore_index=True)
    return OutputDf
```

Or, you give the pd.concat() part to return, but it will be harder to read, so that, it is your decision. Just don't forget to use [] in your code, be careful that the usage of concat:

```
pd.concat([process1, process2])  # use [] inside concat for dataframes
```

If you directly use pd.concat(process1, process2), it will give an error.